# save image from screen to my assets?

Tags: objective-c

This might be a hard thing to do , but 
I have to save whats appears on the screen in some moment, to a file.
but not just a file, i need to save it to my assets folder:
my goal is that i can later use the image without the:

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**but just to use it like it was on my assets**, just to use: `@"myImage.png"` , when `myImage` is the image that i have already saved from my print screen .

any direction on how to do that ?
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't save it to app bundle.
I suggest you to write your own methods to load an image like [UIImage imageNamedCustom:...].
It would be nice if this method will search image in assets first, if not found try to load from Documents or Caches. Also, it may cache path to saved images. After that you can replace all occurences of "[UIImage imageNamed:" to "[UIImage imageNamedCustom:" and other similar methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your app's main bundle is part of the app, and is read-only. You can't add or remove content from it on the device. You're going to have to save that image to one of the directories in your app's sandbox, like `Documents` or `Library/Caches`.

Instead of `+[UIImage imagedNamed:]`, perhaps [`+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW12) would work for you?

Comment: thanks. i know how to get the UIImage from screen, but i want to save it in a way so that i can just use it as a string in my code with @"myImage.png". this is because i already have code that is looking for images in my assets and i dont want to change it now ..

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying, if I understand correctly, is that you want to save part of a drawing on your screen in an image (which is easy) and want to retrieve that later from your application bundle (I presume you mean that instead of the term assets). This can not be done, because the application bundle is read-only at runtime.